# jQuery form validate plugin: Remote check with JSON-Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-plugins

I use the query form validate plugin (http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) for validating some form fields via remote check, Below is my working demo code:

```
username: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 25,
    remote: "/dir/checkvalue.php"
}
```

The php script echoes just `false` or `true` as a string and the validation via the plugin is working fine. For some reasons I've to change the php's output to JSON, so it would be:

```
{"STATUS":false} or {"STATUS":true}
```

I don't know how to handle this JSON response in my js plugin conf array - any help appreciated, Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways you can manage what is done with the remote option ([see the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method)), such as passing an object to remote instead of your the URL.  That object can be any of the settings described in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Unfortunately, to my knowledge, there isn't any way to modify the returned data and have that passed back to jQuery Validate.